# how to know if the proxy is used in the http post request c#

Tags: c#, proxy, request

I did a program that does a post request but I have no idea on how to know if the proxy worked or not.

My code is way to big to put everything here...

I got no error and got a response at the end of my request but does that mean that the proxy is really used?

2nd question, is there a difference between :

1. `this.myproxy = new WebProxy(proxyURL + ":" + port);`
   and
2. `this.myproxy = new WebProxy(proxyURL, port);`

Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: Switch off the proxy and run your code again.

Comment: @john it is a free proxy I found on the web to test :/

Comment: You can always use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to verify no errors are occurring and request contains the proxy.

Comment: @jdwengyup I think I will use that but thought something easier existed

Comment: @lucky You could also make a request to a service like [this "what is my ip" type page](https://api.ipify.org?format=json) using a high-anonymity proxy (i.e. one that doesn't reveal your IP using `x-forwarded-for`)